# How to combine multiple h5 files?

Tags: hdf5, pytorch

Limited by the device, I could only produce several h5 files (the format of each file are same with shape of [idx, 1, 224, 224]) for huge dataset (>100GB) and now I'm confused about the solution to combine these files into a single one for further training on PyTorch. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eTQp.png)

Answer (score 1):

In h5py, groups and files support copy(), which can be used to move groups (including the root group) and their contents between files.

See the docs here (scroll down a bit to find copy()):

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html

The HDF5 distribution also includes a command-line tool called h5copy that can be used to move things around, and the C API has an H5Ocopy() function.